# How to disable a menu item from redirecting or loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, menu, load

I have a menu that if you click it it loads external content then fades it in to the page. How could i tell my link that if the url is already the same to not load the any ajax at all because it would be redundant. And/or if the content loaded is already identical to not call the ajax function and have the link do nothing still. This is so that the only time the ajax is being called is if there is truly new content to be added.

The current page is "Clients" and the user tries to click the "Clients"'s menu nav button, it reloads the content. I want it to do nothing since that is going to make the same content fade in again.

```
$(nav[0]).click(function(){
  $("#load").load("http://imagativa.com/ #load");
  $("#load").fadeIn(300);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to do this. The most common is to return false at the end.

```
 $(nav[0]).click(function(){
   $("#load").load("http://imagativa.com/ #load");
   $("#load").fadeIn(300);
   return false;
 });
```

Or the other method is as follows

```
 $(nav[0]).click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     ....code....
 });
```

Comment: But what will happen when i load new content wont the link still be disabled? If i load new content the link has to reset.

Comment: All the return false; and e.preventDefault() is stop the <a> link from executing. Or redirecting to the href attribute. If you have the button disabled after click. Then you will have to add a way to re-enable the button (normally reverse of the way you disable). I would rarely use this on a site navigation, due to SEO. Not everything on the site may be indexed if the <a> have no real href.

Comment: I actually made a <ul> of the real URL's and gave them a text-indent:-3000px; so that the user wouldn't see them :P but the Search engine shoud; :P that fine though thanks for the input.